# Kubuntu desktop audio stutters

Tags: linux, music, kubuntu, amarok

I've tried using Amarok, mplayer, and VLC on Kubuntu 9.04, and with every one, the audio that plays will randomly stutter (pause for a second and resume). It can happen once per song, ten times per song, or not at all per song. This is with MP3s. I have not checked specifically with WMA or OGG files, as most of my music is MP3.

I have tried changing the driver order, but it always occurs. It seems to recognize the card correctly, so I don't know what the problem could be.

It happens whether music is the only thing playing, so CPU usage hovers around 10%, or when the CPU is around 80% while doing things. Flash videos in Firefox work just fine, no stuttering, and VOB files don't stutter either.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

EDIT: This is an AMD Sempron computer with a K8M800 chipset (I believe, not at the computer at the moment). It has UniChrome video and a basic onboard card (that previously worked perfectly on 7.04 and 8.04).

Further edit: Turning off ktorrent and ensuring that the audio program is the only thing running (including killing apache, et al) makes the audio stutter less often, usually, but doesn't remove the problem.

Another edit: Apparently, even though I looked and didn't see PulseAudio before, it was chosen now when I looked. This is also contrary to everything I found online saying that Ubuntu used it but not Kubuntu, even on the Ubuntu site. I changed it to "VIA8237 with ALC655" and it is working better. It has stuttered some but nowhere near as bad as before. For the moment I will accept an answer.

Comment: As a clarification, Pulseaudio is not used in Kubuntu at all, according to this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578

Comment: can you verify chipset and mention what audio driver your ALSA is currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a lot of hard drive activity while playing music? Since you're streaming music from the disk, a lot of other use of that disk could cause this.

The other likely culprit is that there's something wrong with your sound backend. Did Kubuntu make the switch to PulseAudio? I've heard a lot of horror stories about it -- if it did you might want to try switching to ALSA.

Comment: I will have to check for Pulseaudio when I get home. I have ktorrent running in the background, downloading to the same disk I'm playing from. I don't know if ktorrent is running every time it happens, though. Still doesn't explain why it worked flawlessly with the previous version, even with ktorrent running.

Comment: Don't see the Pulseaudio reference, and closing everything makes the problem less frequent, though only slightly.

Comment: No Pulseaudio in Kubuntu. I have verified it finally.

Answer (score 0):

installed mozilla-plugin-vlc worked for me in Kubuntu YEAH fewwww ! Just that simple and might want to try vlc-plugin-pulse too, Good Luck